# Как правильно делить ссылку на Url и Get в Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Есть ссылка для получения Json
https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/latest?symbols=AUD%2CEUR%2CJPY%2CMDL%2CRUB&base=USD

Если я использую `Retrofit`? как правильно её делить:

```
private val BASE_URL = "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/"

...


@GET("latest?symbols=AUD%2CEUR%2CJPY%2CMDL%2CRUB&base=USD")
fun loadExchangeRateApi(): Call<ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>>
```

или

```
private val BASE_URL = "https://api.apilayer.com/"
    
    ...
    

    @GET("exchangerates_data/latest?symbols=AUD%2CEUR%2CJPY%2CMDL%2CRUB&base=USD")
    fun loadExchangeRateApi(): Call<ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как хотите. В `BASE_URL` вы задаёте базовый адрес, относительно которого будут строиться все запросы. Если запросов несколько - целесообразно выделить в базовый адрес ту часть, которая совпадает у всех.
Это не обязательно - это для вашего удобства, чтобы не писать адрес целиком в каждый запрос.